# Displaying Twitter on Shopify without running into any API limit issues

Tags: php, mysql, api, twitter, shopify

I am looking to add a twitter feed (using the jTweetAnywhere.js plugin) with Shopify. Although I have it working, I am concerned I will run into Twitter's API limit issues. As far as I know, Shopify does NOT allow you to use PHP, so I am not sure how to cache and recall any tweets.

Are they any suggestions as to how I can cache Tweets and then recall them WITHOUT PHP and MYSQL?

Thank you so much!

Jenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the Twitter rate limits apply to an IP, if there are thousands of hits on a Shop at once, it appears to Twitter that the IP's are from the various customers' computers, so hitting the limits should not count in your case. It is not as if all the hits will appear to be coming from Shopify's data centre.